# I am trying to make a cursor move when a button does

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to make a button that moves when the cursor does so it is just the cursor can't click it but it is attached to it but cannot be clicked. I am using this but it is not working (btw I am new to javascript so idk if it was supposed to work or not): `document.addEventListener('mousemove',runAway,true)`

Comment: It would be great if you make a reproducible example here.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I know I explained it horribly. So I am trying to make a button that is attached to the cursor so it is fairly hard to "click". I tried using ```document.addEventListener('mousemove',runAway,true)``` butt it was not working for me. Could you help me or give me an example of how to fix it?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what exactly you want. You can show an example of the desired result.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Ok here is an example (I am trying to replicate it) actual-un-clickable-button.baconman321.repl.co there. That is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event `mousemove` in conjunction with the event `event` delegation, to which you need to transfer the coordinates of the mouse by **X** and **Y**:

```
x = event.pageX;
y = event.pageY;
```

Next, we pass the current coordinates **+10 pixels** to the button (to prevent the button from being clicked), using property `left` and `top`:

```
button.style.left = x + 10 + "px";
button.style.top = y + 10 + "px";
```

Likewise, the moving element must be **relative** or **absolute**.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;
    button.style.left = x + 10 + "px";
    button.style.top = y + 10 + "px";
});
```

```css
button {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button>Moving button</button>
```